# c# ShowWindow (hWnd, 0) not hiding window

Tags: c#, console, window, hide

When I compile the below code into an executable and run it, the console windows appears.  From the texts that I've read `ShowWindow(hWnd,0)` should hide the console window, but it doesn't.

This is the below code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace Foreground {
  class GetForegroundWindowTest {

    /// Foreground dll's
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling=true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true)]
    public static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

    /// Console hide dll's
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    const int SW_HIDE = 0;

    public static void Main(string[] args){
        while (true){
            IntPtr fg = GetForegroundWindow(); //use fg for some purpose

            var bufferSize = 1000;
            var sb = new StringBuilder(bufferSize);

            GetWindowText(fg, sb, bufferSize);

            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("C:\\Office Viewer\\OV_Log.txt")) 
            {
                sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss,") + sb.ToString());
            }

            var handle = GetConsoleWindow();
            Console.WriteLine(handle);
            ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);

            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone explain to me where the problem in the code is?

`Console.WriteLine(handle)` was a line put in to show me and you that the program is grabbing the handle, but it just isn't minimising the window to which the handle represents.

Please note:  I'd refer a code based answer as opposed to an "alter IDE settings" answer.

Comment: Maybe you don't have enough right. Check the return code of the ShowWindow(). Run GetLastError() if it has return false

Comment: Console.WriteLine(handle) return a 6 digit number.  That mean's, if i'm correct, that I am getting the console handle.  I'm and confused because even though I'm getting the handle, it's not hiding cmd.

Answer (score 3):

Took a while to figure it out but here's the working code.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace Foreground {
  class GetForegroundWindowTest {

    /// Foreground dll's
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling=true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true)]
    public static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool FreeConsole();

    /// Console hide dll's
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    const int SW_HIDE = 0;

    public static void Main(string[] args){
        while (true){
            IntPtr fg = GetForegroundWindow(); //use fg for some purpose

            var bufferSize = 1000;
            var sb = new StringBuilder(bufferSize);

            GetWindowText(fg, sb, bufferSize);

            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("C:\\Office Viewer\\OV_Log.txt")) 
            {
                sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss,") + sb.ToString());
            }

            var handle = GetConsoleWindow();
            Console.WriteLine(handle);
            ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);

            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
private static extern int ShowWindow(int hwnd, int nCmdShow);
```

to hide a window. This method takes the integer handler of the window (instead of pointer). Using **[Spy++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460729.aspx)** (in Visual Studio tools) you can get the **Class Name** and **Window Name** of the window which you want to hide. Then you can do as follows

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int ShowWindow(int hwnd, int nCmdShow);

const int SW_HIDE = 0;

public void hideScannerDialog()
        {
            // retrieve the handler of the window  
            int iHandle = FindWindow("ClassName", "WindowName"); //The className & WindowName I got using Spy++
            if (iHandle > 0)
            {
                // Hide the window using API        
                ShowWindow(iHandle, SW_HIDE);
            }
        }
```